# 96 Chevy Cavilier Leak From the Transmission

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, manual-transmission, leak, cavalier

I'm looking at buying a 96 Chevy Cavilier which looks from the pictures to be in very well kept condition.  The only drawback the seller mentioned was an unknown leak from the manual transmission.  Can anyone give me an idea how serious this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on where the leak is coming from. There are about three wear places where a front wheel drive manual transmission could be leaking from. Either where the input shaft goes in or where the axle shafts connect into the transmission. It could possibly be leaking from other gasketed areas (for instance where the transmission splits), but this is unlikely. Usually these areas don't leak unless the seal is broken.

The axle shaft seals are relatively easy to change, but take some work to do so. You have to remove the axle shafts to get to them. The input shaft seal on the transmission is a lot more involved because you have to remove and break apart the engine/transmission to get to the seal.

It could possibly be leaking from where the shifter mechanism enters the transmission, but IIRC, this is in the top or upper portion of the transmission which would be above the tranny fluid line. At worst you get a small seepage from this area and not a full blown leak.

Depending on how bad the leak is will determine how serious it is. If it's only a drip every 100 miles, it's not a serious thing ... *yet*. You would need to keep an eye on it and ensure you are not running low. If there is a small puddle on the driveway that continually grows day-after-day, this is an issue. Could you run the vehicle this way? Sure, as long as you keep the fluids topped off. This becomes a pain in the butt after a while as usually the fill/check hole for the transmission is not in the greatest of locations. It usually requires getting under the vehicle in order to make it happen. Then you have the environmental impacts, keeping your car and driveway clean, cost of purchasing fluid, and [the smell](https://octopart.com/10-4016-ac+delco-57609932).

Answer (score 0):

It might be Transmission fluid leak.

Here is a very good explanation and STEP by STEP DIY on how to check for transmission fluid leak on your partiacular car.

[Checking transmission oil leaks on cavalier](http://www.ehow.com/how_4793597_check-transmission-fluid-chevy-cavalier.html)

After the check , fix the leak , that's the best solution.

That said, it wont cause much of a problem if you don't change it often, change it every 100,000 miles.

Comment: The link you provided is for an automatic transmission ... I don't think it applies in this case.

Comment: Oh.. ok.. didnt notice

Comment: No worries  :-) It happens to the best of us.

Comment: Shall i delete this post?

Comment: No. I think what you are saying is valid. You might want to see if you can find a link for something on a manual transmission, though.